# How to always show vertices in edge select mode in blender?

Tags: workflow, customization, selection-tools

I work in *edge select mode* to select and delete some edges but at the same time, I want to see vertices so I can decide which edges to delete.

I do not  want to change between *vertex selection mode* and *edge select mode*.

Is it possible in blender 2.9+ to always show vertices in *edge select mode*?

Answer (score 6):

You can have both *edge select mode* and *vertex select mode* active at once by holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: Thank  you, this answered y question